# cannot find MoveNextAsync for MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

From: https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/query/

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("restaurants");
var filter = new BsonDocument();
var count = 0;
using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter))
{
    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        var batch = cursor.Current;
        foreach (var document in batch)
        {
            // process document
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using visual studio 2012 and CSharpDriver-2.2.0.
Visual studio says that it cannot find MoveNextAsync method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the method must be async, i try this code and work for me check if you have this

`using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using MongoDB.Shared;`